# What does steam do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When excavating and building structures, some tiles have 'steam'. This causes the excavation to be more expensive. What other effects does it have?

Comment: It's a platform for buying and downloading digital...  oh wait, nevermind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build a *Thermo Generator* over the "Steam" areas. These offer power far more efficiently than *Power Stations*, as they give +20 power instead of +6.

Comment: yea, thermal generators are awesome until you get access to elerium generators.

Comment: @yx. Even after that, they're cheaper and don't take UFO power sources.

Comment: true, but I can place my generators around the thermal vent to get adjacency bonuses.  I think on classic you only get 1 steam vent rather than 2 (or maybe its random and I just had bad luck on that start)

Comment: It's random. I've started 20+ Classic Ironman games now, and have seen anywhere from 1 to 3 steam vents.

Comment: hmm... so to maximize the chances of a classic ironman playthrough I should probably restart until I get 3 steam vents fairly close in proximity to each other...

Comment: @yx. I've strongly considered doing some restarts until I get a steam vent that's right next to the access lift. Had one game so far where that happened, and it was *sweeeeeet*. Of course, I still lost horribly.

Comment: Note that Thermo Generators are only more efficient in terms of **space**, *not* **cost**. They cost $200 for 20 power, while the regular generator is $60 for 6, so both cost $10 per power unit.